# Indicator lamp for 100W circuit?

Tags: led, resistors

I am making a dummy load for a 100W tube guitar amplifier. I know the basics but I'm trying to be really careful since I'm dealing with a lot of power. My dummy load is just a 100W 8Ω resistor, complete with heat sink, and I have a simple box with the circuit constructed in it and it's all working and ready to go. However, I've been nervous about what happens if the resistor fails somehow. Having that load on the output transformer is essential to keeping my amp from frying so I wondered if there was a good way to have some kind of indicator that something in the circuit has failed and the dummy load is no longer providing any load to the amplifier. Even something as simple as an LED in series would be nice, but with the high amount of wattage going through the circuit I'm not sure that there is a simple indicator bulb that would work.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I could do?

Image from comments (SSR edit):

[image]

Comment: fails short - how about a fuse?  fails open -  add multiple larger R's in parallel?

Comment: I don't need a way to open the circuit, but rather an easy way to tell that the circuit is open without having to put a multimeter on it or anything

Comment: What is the intended use with a dummy load?  You can use an 8W 12V bulb in series.

Comment: Ok... so you want an LED that tests continuity when the amp is in 'standby' ?  A little more involved but I think you could do it ....  would involve changing the "standby" switch to SPDT or SP3T etc

Comment: Standby does what, heat the filaments but not the other power supply?

Comment: on a guitar amp? I think so. Point being it disconnects the output

Comment: not a finished idea, just a [thought](https://ibb.co/cbXg6bJ) . plz review and use caution.

Comment: I'm with @Pete W - design the load so it is unlikely it will fail. Besides, a valve amp just goes red in the face if it is overloaded unlike a transistor amp that goes 'pop' in a microsecond. If you want a simple 1kW load - modify a toaster.

Comment: just to be super clear the thing with the opto isn't at that level. my thought process was that if anything breaks, it'd be the led or opto and not any part of the amp.